# ChromeDriver version do not support the Google Chrome version

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci, webdriver-io

i am using following tech stack while automating web specific test cases:

```
1. WebDriverIO for web automation
2. Travis as a CI tool
3. I am using `selenium-standalone` as a `service` - This is webdriverIO specific thing
```

The `travis.yml` file looks like below:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '18.16.0'

dist: jammy

addons:
  chrome: stable

before_install:
  - # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
  
install:
  - npm install

script:
  - npm run generic
  - npm run login
  - npm run signup
```

when I run any test from the listed testsuite, I ran into following Error:

```
Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 117
[0-0] Current browser version is 116.0.5845.187 with binary path /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

Is there any way not to encounter this issue again? Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I was just running into a similar issue on Heroku CI and ended up getting rid of the chromedriver etc buildpacks - as well as any env vars holding path to Chrome - and then just relying on the new [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) to handle automatically retrieving the right version of chromedriver.